# menu zoom in and zoom out width issue

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation

i need help to adjust horizontal menu width with zoom in or zoom out

**Chrome 100%**

[image]

**Chrome 90%**

[image]

**Here My Html Code & Css**

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/DnyVS/][3]
```

Comment: A clear explanation of what you would like to achieve would be helpful.

Comment: @Adam'Sacki'Sackfield menu not working properly in different resolution i need to adjust it

Comment: @Farhan Dharsi please select me as best answer if it solved your question.

Answer (score 1):

Include below css.I have added new rule "margin-left:-1px"

```
.ddsmoothmenu ul li a {
display: block;
color: #FFF;
padding: 0px 20px;
line-height: 31px;
text-decoration: none;
border-right: #FFF solid 1px;
margin-left:-1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS

```
.ddsmoothmenu ul li a {
display: block;
color: #FFF;
padding: 0px 20px;
line-height: 31px;
text-decoration: none;
border-right: #FFF solid 1px;
}
```

Padding affects in there design
This code will work perfectly until 50% zoom out